# How to create a not Box symbol?

Tags: symbols

Like the command `\notin`, I want to create a `\notBox`.

So far I have made `$\Box\!\!\!\!\diagdown$`, but it does not look good.

May be I need to raise the `\diagdown` by a little.

Please help making such a symbol.

Comment: @Werner As usual, I completely forgot the simplest solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `stackengine` do the work for you!

I have also changed `\diagdown` with
`/` to make the symbol similar to `\notin`.

*Edit*: I've added a solution without `stackengine`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\notBox}{\mathrel{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{$/$}{$\Box$}}}

\newcommand{\notBoxsimple}{\mathrel{\ooalign{$\Box$\cr$\raise.24ex\hbox{$\mkern2.1mu/$}$\cr}}}

\begin{document}
    Benchmark:
    \[
    A \notin B
    \]
    With \texttt{stackengine}:
    \[
    A \notBox B 
    \]
    Without \texttt{stackengine}:
    \[
    A \notBoxsimple B 
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your output is different than the command provided. But the command is correct.  I got what I need. Thanks.

Comment: @G_0_pi_i_e Sorry, I wrote my answer with my smartphone and I unwillingly mirrored the image while I was cropping it. It should be correct now, please check, thank you!

Comment: It is not working everywhere the same way. In one of my article the `/` gets misplaced.

Comment: Is it possible to make without using `stackengine` package

Comment: @G_0_pi_i_e Of course, it is possible, now I'll try to add an alternative solution, but it's strange that it doesn't work, could you please add an MWE of the case where it doesn't work?

Comment: Presence of `\usepackage{latexsym}` creates the problem.

Comment: @G_0_pi_i_e Problably `latexsym` modifies the dymension of `/`. In that case you can simply raise a bit the `/`: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} \usepackage{latexsym} \usepackage{stackengine} \newcommand{\notBox}{\mathrel{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{.2ex}{$/‌$}{$\Box$}}} \begin{document} \[ A_1\notBox A_2 \] \end{document}`

Comment: @G_0_pi_i_e For a solution without `stackengine`, see my renewed answer.